# How to use R after updating Gradle plugin version 3.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have updated my gradle plugin version to 3.3, after syncing the project cannot resolve R.

Comment: There is likely some error happening in processing your resources. Look at the logs, and for files marked with errors under `res/`.

Comment: But if I roll back the update, the error is gone. Also the project works fine, it just that it cannot resolve the R class.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding the project, and invalidating caches/restart?

Comment: Yes I have..still the same

Comment: Unresolved `R` generally means, as I said, that there's some error happening in processing your resources. What do your logs say? Are there any files marked with errors under `res/`?

Comment: Android Studio 3.3 and newest gradle seem to cause many problems for now. Use old one. Check build.gradle files if you want to use gradle 4.10.x and plugin 3.3.x.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it just like you said something to do with my res. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have at least Gradle version 4.10.1 ([as per Android guidelines](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin))
- Clean project (Build -> Clean) and rebuild (Build -> Rebuild Project)
- Invalidate cache (File -> Invadiate caches / Restart) and rebuild

Comment: Issue got resolved, some error in my resource file.Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

There were big changes around gradle plugin [3.3.0 (January 2019)](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-3-0) / Gradle 4.10.x

> Behavior changes
>
> - Lazy task configuration: The plugin now uses Gradle’s new task creation API ...
> - Faster R class generation for library projects
>
> ...

build.config files for project and modules may produce errors related to these changes. Check them.

---

Notes.

I've experienced a VCS(git) related issue with Android Studio 3.3.0 which disturbs builds. In editor, some files does not show current contents, showing intermediate or unrelated files, etc. It also happens with older Gradle version, so it seems an Android Studio specific problem.

Same project with AS 3.2.x, Gradle plugin 3.2.1, Gradle 4.7: no problem,

with AS 3.2.x, Gradle plugin 3.3.0, Gradle 4.10.2: another problem (compatibility related).

Comment: Above mentioned issue is resolved, and I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

I tried all of the following:

- Clean project (Build -> Clean) and rebuild (Build -> Rebuild Project)
- Clean project from terminal (gradlew clean) and rebuild (gradlew build) did the trick.
- Invalidate cache (File -> Invalidate caches / Restart) and rebuild.
- Check `res/` directory and check all file.

My problem was not resolved!!!

In the final step, I updated the Android Studio 3.4

My problem was fixed, and now I working with the latest gradle (gradle-5.1.1-all.zip) and gradle plugin (3.4.0)

**note : Update your Android studio, which has tried all the methods..**

Comment: Issue got resolved, some error in my resource file.Thanks anyway